# How do I make an activity wait until Facebook login is complete?

Tags: button, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to make an application for the Android platform. So far I have two activities. Both have fragments. The first activity at the moment is using the Facebook api so that users can sign in. I want my first activity to switch to the second activity once the login is complete. I tried using an onClickListener with an intent, but the second activity would start before the login was completed. I have sense reverted my code to the point where there is no onClicklistener or intent. Any help would be appreciated. I did try reading the documentation for intents and activities, but I couldn't figure out how to do what I wanted. I will post my code bellow.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

next

```
package com.tfs.taylor.retreat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView mTextDetails;
private AccessTokenTracker mTokenTracker;
  private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
  private CallbackManager mCallBackManager;


    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack= new            FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayWelcomeMessage(profile);



    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};
public MainFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    mCallBackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    mTokenTracker=new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

        }
    };

    mProfileTracker=new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldprofile, Profile newprofile) {

        }
    };

    mTokenTracker.startTracking();
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();





}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}
private void displayWelcomeMessage(Profile profile) {
    if (profile != null) {
        mTextDetails.setText("Welcome " + profile.getName());
    }
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallBackManager, mCallBack);
    mTextDetails=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_details);




}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    displayWelcomeMessage(profile);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    mTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallBackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call new activity in your onSuccess method. By this your activity is called only after user logged in Successfully.

```html
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack= new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
 @Override
  public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
   AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
   Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
   displayWelcomeMessage(profile);

   //call new activity here.
}
```